# Sending value of radio button to canvas element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a slight problem that got me stuck on this project.

Heres my index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Snake Game - WP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style_settings.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="gamesettings"><h1>Customise your game</h1>
        <form id="colorformsnake" name="colorformsnake" onchange="return getRadioValSnake()"><label>Choose the snake color: <br/><br/>

            Green: <input type="radio" id="green" value="green"  name="snakecolor"><br /><br />
            Red: <input type="radio" id="red" value="red" name="snakecolor" checked="checked"/><br /><br />
            Blue: <input type="radio" value="blue" id="blue" name="snakecolor"></label><br /><br/><br /></form>

        <form id="colorformbg" onchange="getRadioValBg()" name="colorformbg">
            <label>Choose the background color: <br /><br/>
                Gray: <input type="radio" id="gray" value="gray" name="bgcolor" ><br /><br />
                White: <input type="radio" id="white" value="white" name="bgcolor"/><br /><br />
                Black: <input type="radio" value="black" id="black" name="bgcolor" checked="checked"></label><br /><br><br /></form>
    </div>

<div class="game">
    <div id="main">
        <canvas id="gamecanvas" width="350" height="350"></canvas><br /><br />
        <p style="color: #8f00b3">Press START to play the game!</p>
        <input type="submit" id="startbutton" value="START">
    </div>
</div>
    <div id="scores">
        <form id="scoresForm">
            <h1>User scores: </h1>
            <label>Show top 5 highscores:<br /><br /> <button id="showbutton">SHOW</button></label><br /><br />
            <div id="showScores"></div><br /><br />
            <label>Show last 5 players:<br /><br /> <button id="showbuttonlast">SHOW</button></label>
            <div id="showScoresLast"></div></form>
    </div>

<script src="javascript/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/colorsettings.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/initial_config.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/draw.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/app.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/ajax.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see here I have groups of radio buttons with different values. Now what I want to do is that the user selects one of the colours and depending on the chosen value I would like to change an element colour of a canvas aka in this example a snake.

Here is what i've partially succeeded in doing.

This is a file called colorsettings.js where i declared functions for getting the value in a variable.

```js
var snakecolor=" ";
var bgcolor="";
var snakecolorCurrent;
var currentcolor;

function getRadioValSnake()
{
    snakecolor=($('input[name="snakecolor"]:checked', '#colorformsnake').val());
    currentcolor=snakecolor;
    if(currentcolor=='red'){return 'red'}
    if(currentcolor=='green'){return 'green'}
    if(currentcolor=='blue'){return 'blue'}
}

function getRadioValBg()
{
    bgcolor=($('input[name="bgcolor"]:checked', '#colorformbg').val());
    return bgcolor;
}

snakecolorCurrent=getRadioValSnake();
console.log(snakecolorCurrent);
```

What happens here is that it works, but only partially. Namely, the value that works OK is the one that is marked as checked="checked" in the original index.html file and it displays the snake in that colour. If I try choosing a different colour nothing happens, its stays red. If i remove the checked="checked" element from one of the buttons i get unidentified as a value.

Here is the final snippet, which is the draw.js file, here is where my variable should affect the colour of the snake.

```js
var drawModule = (function () {

    var bodySnake =function (x, y) {

        // the color settings start here
        if(snakecolorCurrent=="red"){
        context.fillStyle='red';
        context.fillRect(x * snakeSize, y * snakeSize, snakeSize, snakeSize);
        context.strokeStyle = '#BCBCBC';
        context.strokeRect(x * snakeSize, y * snakeSize, snakeSize, snakeSize);}

        if(snakecolorCurrent=="blue")
        {
        context.fillStyle='blue';
        context.fillRect(x * snakeSize, y * snakeSize, snakeSize, snakeSize);
        context.strokeStyle = '#BCBCBC';
        context.strokeRect(x * snakeSize, y * snakeSize, snakeSize, snakeSize);}

        if(snakecolorCurrent=="green")
        {
            context.fillStyle='green';
            context.fillRect(x * snakeSize, y * snakeSize, snakeSize, snakeSize);
            context.strokeStyle = '#BCBCBC';
            context.strokeRect(x * snakeSize, y * snakeSize, snakeSize, snakeSize);}
    };
    //and finish here
    var snakeFood = function (x, y) {
        context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
        context.fillRect(x * snakeSize, y * snakeSize, snakeSize, snakeSize);
        context.fillStyle = 'red';
        context.fillRect(x * snakeSize + 1, y * snakeSize + 1, snakeSize - 2, snakeSize - 2);
    };

    var scoreText = function () {
        var score_text = "Score: " + score;
        context.fillStyle = 'white';
        context.fillText(score_text, 145, h - 5);
    };

    var drawSnake = function () {
        var length = 4;
        snake = [];
        for (var i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            snake.push({x: i, y: 0});
        }
    };

    var paint = function () {
        context.fillStyle = 'gray';
        context.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        context.strokeStyle = 'black';
        context.strokeRect(0, 0, w, h);

        startbutton.setAttribute('disabled', true);

        var snakeX = snake[0].x;
        var snakeY = snake[0].y;

        if (direction == 'right') {
            snakeX++;
        }
        else if (direction == 'left') {
            snakeX--;
        }
        else if (direction == 'up') {
            snakeY--;
        } else if (direction == 'down') {
            snakeY++;
        }

        if (snakeX == -1 || snakeX == w / snakeSize || snakeY == -1 || snakeY == h / snakeSize || checkCollision(snakeX, snakeY, snake)) {
            //restart game
            var name = prompt ('Please enter your username:',''); // we ask the user for their name

                if(confirm("This is your username: "+name+ "\n And this is your score:" +score)){loadData()}

            startbutton.removeAttribute('disabled', true);

            context.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
            gameloop = clearInterval(gameloop);
            return;}


        if (snakeX == food.x && snakeY == food.y) {
            var tail = {x: snakeX, y: snakeY}; //Create a new head instead of moving the tail
            score++;

            createFood(); //Create new food
        } else {
            tail = snake.pop(); //pops out the last cell
            tail.x = snakeX;
            tail.y = snakeY;
        }
        //The snake can now eat the food.
        snake.unshift(tail); //puts back the tail as the first cell

        for (var i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
            bodySnake(snake[i].x, snake[i].y);
        }

        snakeFood(food.x, food.y);
        scoreText();
    };

    var createFood = function () {
        food =
        {
            x: Math.floor((Math.random() * 30) + 1),
            y: Math.floor((Math.random() * 30) + 1)
        };
        for (var i = 0; i > snake.length; i++) {
            var snakeX = snake[i].x;
            var snakeY = snake[i].y;

            if (food.x === snakeX && food.y === snakeY || food.y === snakeY && food.x === snakeX) {
                food.x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 30) + 1);
                food.y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 30) + 1);
            }
        }
    };

    var checkCollision = function (x, y, array) {
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i].x === x && array[i].y === y)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    };

    var init = function () {
        direction = 'down';
        drawSnake();
        createFood();
        gameloop = setInterval(paint, 80);
    };


    return {
        init: init
    };


}());
```

I hope I was understandable. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't think `$('input[name="snakecolor"]:checked', '#colorformsnake')` is the correct way to specify context in jQuery. Try `$('input[name="snakecolor"]:checked', $('#colorformsnake'))` or the more logical `$("#colorformsnake input[name="snakecolor"]:checked")`

Comment: @apokryfos thanks for your answer. But even if i do change it to those its still not working unfortunately

Comment: It was more like an information comment rather than a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it. What i needed to do is call a function directly to the value of the canvas, like this.

```js
var bodySnake =function (x, y) {

        context.fillStyle=getRadioValSnake();
        context.fillRect(x * snakeSize, y * snakeSize, snakeSize, snakeSize);
        context.strokeStyle = '#BCBCBC';
        context.strokeRect(x * snakeSize, y * snakeSize, snakeSize, snakeSize);
    };
```